# JPA/Hibernate/Spring - Primary key exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

Eclipse throws me an exception -  Duplicate entry '201805091-1' for key 'PRIMARY'. I understand that exception, but I do not understand why the code below makes a new record in my database. I thought this should work like: If the combination of date and doctors id does not exist - then make it otherwise use the combination that is currently in database. But there must be obviously something wrong...

Thank you very much :)

```
OperationsDate od = null; // these 6 lines of the code may be problematic

        if(em.find(OperationsDate.class, id) != null) {
            od = em.find(OperationsDate.class, id);
        } else {
            od = new OperationsDate(id);
        }

public void process(List<Integer> list, int doctorId, String pin, boolean inf) {
        Patient p = em.find(Patient.class, pin);
        Doctor d = em.find(Doctor.class, doctorId);

        p.addDoctor(d);
        d.addPatient(p);

        int id = countId(doctorId);

        OperationsDate od = null;

        if(em.find(OperationsDate.class, id) != null) {
            od = em.find(OperationsDate.class, id);
        } else {
            od = new OperationsDate(id);
        }

        if(inf) {
            for(int number : list) {
                Medicine m = em.find(Medicine.class, number);

                od.setDoctor(d);
                d.addOperationsDate(od);
                od.addMedicine(m);
                m.addOperationsDate(od);
            }
        } else {
            Operation o = em.find(Operation.class, list.get(0));

            od.setDoctor(d);
            d.addOperationsDate(od);
            od.addOperation(o);
            o.addOperationsDate(od);
        }

    }

public int countId(int doctorId) {
        long millis=System.currentTimeMillis();  
        java.sql.Date date=new java.sql.Date(millis);  

        String id = "";
        String date2 = date.toString();
        for(int i=0; i < date2.length();i++) {
            if(i == 4 || i == 7) {
                continue;
            }
            id += date2.charAt(i);
        }
        id += doctorId;
        int id2 = Integer.parseInt(id);

        return id2;
    }
```

Comment: Well, you **are** creating a new `OperationsDate` entity by doing so: `od = new OperationsDate(id);` Whether you want to persist it or not is another matter. Is your `process` method inside a transaction? Your question is a little unclear about the result, do you want to create this entity or not?  BTW, don't invoke twice the `find` method to get the same object, just assign it directly to the variable and null-check it.

Comment: thanks for your response :) yes, i have @Transactional in my service layer. I want to save a record to database in case that database does not contain it...

Answer (score 0):

Just try it this way then, as I told you in my comment:

```
    OperationsDate od = em.find(OperationsDate.class, id);
    if( od == null) {
        od = new OperationsDate(id);
    }
    ...
    // potential persist or merge, depending on your frameworks configuration regarding autocommit and such
    em.persist(od);
```

If it still doesn't work, add the code for your entities, to make sure nothing's wrong about it.